# "data.description" and other similar kind of statements [jquery, ajax, servlet, json]

Tags: jquery

Sorry in advance if the question has been already asked (and hopefully answered).

I'm studying javascript with the use of Jquery and Ajax (plus JSON) calls to a servlet. While searching around for examples I got through a simple code that has some "dark point". I'm struggling for checking what kind of thing I've stumbled upon.
Here's an example of the code

```
function on_login_success(){
  $("#display").text(data.description);
  ....
 }
```

I understood (I think) how the ajax to servlet calls work, but what I can't understand is the meaning of that "data.description" thing.
My question is:
It is something related to JSON? and if it's that (or whatever other thing) could someone give me an example (or even better, some good link) in order me to study that and understand what's going on?
I did some work by myself on the code but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not much to go on here, but `data.description` is accessing the `description` property of the `data` object. It's possible that the object was retrieved via and AJAX request, but without seeing any more of your code we can't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be the server responds with JSON like this

```
       data:{
        "description" : "this is the one"
        }

console.log(data.description); // output's - this is the one
```

Comment: aktiv-coder and Rory, thanks! actually is what I guessed too, but since I'm new to JSON I'd like to be sure about where to focus on my efforts. Thanks again for your help